# Alternate phrase for "I would be happy to"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I had an interview at a company 5 weeks ago.  I received feedback that they "liked" me but need to interview a couple of additional candidate.  I am going to send them an email to let them know I am still interested and that I can be available to meet with them again.  However, I would really appreciate some thoughts on another/better way to express the second part of this sentence since I have already used that phrase previously in the email.

"As you progress in your hiring process, I would be happy to meet again to further discuss my fit with your firm and to get better acquainted."

Specifically, what are some different ways to say
"I would be happy to meet again?"

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughtful responses.  To add some context, I am bringing up the idea/suggesting another meeting.  Also, Calphool, you are absolutely right that I need to mention my general awesomeness (I spend a whole paragraph on my awesomeness in the email).

Comment: Here is how I am thinking of closing the email:                                                                                                     "In summary, I am very excited about the position and I would welcome the opportunity to meet again to further discuss my abilities, my fit with your firm, and to get better acquainted.
Please let me know if you would like to arrange another meeting.
Thanks again and I look forward to hearing from you soon,"

Comment: How about "If you are not yet convinced that I am your ideal candidate, we need to meet again."?

Comment: Vote to close. This has turned into advice on handling a job prospect rather than about the specific topic described in the title and the question. OP needs to manage this better.

Comment: Do people really use expressions like 'my fit', in job applications? Wouldn't you say 'my suitability'? Does 'fit' even exist as a noun, other than in a medical sense e.g. with epilepsy?

Comment: @WS2 Saying that something or someone would be "a good fit" is a very common expression, at least in American English.

Comment: @Nicole *A good fit*, I recognise. And I was wrong, because it is clearly a noun. But the expression used was something like *to discuss my fit*. That seems to me to take liberties with the metaphor which I am thinking might reflect badly on a candidate for employment.

Answer (score 6):

Although it's just a preference, "I would be happy to" sounds a little passive to me.

Use something like:  "I'm excited about the position and look forward to speaking with you again."

Or

"I know I would be great at this job, and I can't wait to talk to you more about *my ideas / my work ethic / my general awesomeness*" (whatever you think they're looking for).

Or even:

"I'll contact you on Wednesday at 9:00am after your other interviews are complete, and we can discuss why I would still be the best candidate."

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives available. Find something that fits you.

> As you progress in your hiring process, I look forward to further discussing my fit with your firm and getting better acquainted.
>
> As you progress in your hiring process, I earnestly hope we can get better acquainted and further discuss my fit with your firm.

Answer (score 2):

- I would be glad to meet with you again.
- I would appreciate the opportunity to meet with you again.
- I would welcome the opportunity to meet with you again.

Comment: Great answers. Ironic that this response had the least upvotes, but was used in Ben's draft reply. 

Also unsettling that this question was closed.

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is clear, polite, and conveys exactly what you mean.  In a more formal context, I would suggest:

- Should you be interested in further discussing my experience and interests, don't hesitate to call me for a second interview.